# Preprocessor directives define and ifdef do not work as I imagined?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have 3 files:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

#define DEBUG

int main()
{
  testFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void testFunction();

#endif // TEST_H_INCLUDED
```

test.c

```
#include "test.h"

void testFunction(){
  #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("I'm inside the testFunction\n");
  #endif
}
```

**THE QUESTION:** Why does the program not print stuff in *#ifdef DEBUG* block? If I write *#define DEBUG* in test.h or test.c everything is fine. What's the problem then *#define DEBUG* in main.c? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Preprocessor directives define and ifdef do not work as I imagined?

No, not quite. You seem to believe that preprocessor directives traverse file boundaries, which they don't. **The scope of a `#define`d preprocessor macro is only the single file it's defined in,** or other files only if those other files `#include` the file containing the macro definition.

Perhaps it would help to imagine that you run the compiler (and thus the preprocessor) on each file *separately* (which you do, even if you don't realize it). There's no way the preprocessor could tell `DEBUG` has been defined in a file which it doesn't operate on.

Answer (score 3):

Because `DEBUG` is `#define`'d in `main.c`, it is not visible in `test.c`.  You need to `#define` it in the build settings, or in a header

Answer (score 2):

Because you defined `DEBUG` inside `main.c` but `test.c` doesn't include `main.c` so while compiling the translation unit the preprocessor symbol is not present.

You should declare global scope macros in a header file and then include it where needed.

Answer (score 1):

You define DEBUG in the main.c -- that is not visible to test.c -- if you want DEBUG to be visible to both main.c and test.c, you should define it in test.h

Answer (score 0):

define DEBUG macro inside the makefile for the global visibility

Comment: That won't help.  The define will still only affect main.c.  You can't effectively re-write test.h in the way you're suggesting